# Linked List arrow operator looping without p=p->link

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, operator-keyword

How can I get to the last node of the linked list that has x numbers of nodes by using multiple arrow operators(->)?

I am curious how I can express do the -> operation x times in my codes

pseoudo code
p (->next)*x

I want to make p->link->link->..... I want to do this x times WITHOUT USING p=p->link

Comment: Is the value of `x` known when the program is compiled?

Comment: Nope! It is unknown!

Comment: We get the linked list from dynamic allocation

Comment: If the goal is to get to the last node without changing `p`, couldn't you just copy the pointer `p` to a different variable?

Comment: The goal is to get the last 4 nodes without changing p or any other pointers !

Comment: Have you considered using a simple loop? `Node n = p; while(n->next) n = n->next;`. On the final iteration, the value of `n` will be the last node in the list.
I am fraid I don't know how to do it without a temporary, especially if the length of the list is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion:

```
struct List
{
    struct List *next;
};


struct List *findLast(struct List *node)
{
    if(node -> next) return findLast(node -> next);
    return node;
}

struct List *findNth(struct List *node, size_t N)
{
    if(N && node -> next) return findLast(node -> next, N - 1)
    if(!N) return node;
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: "I want to make p->link->link->..... I want to do this x times WITHOUT USING p=p->link": Wouldn't this mean `x` would need to be a parameter?

Comment: any comment DV-ter?

Comment: @ScottHunter do you see any assignment here?

Comment: What I don't see is `x`, which would make it hard to do anything `x` times.

Comment: @ScottHunter indeed. If `x` is called `N` then it is not valid. Changing the name of the variable or parameter makes function invalid :) :D

Comment: Sorry; neither `x` nor `N` was originally there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you just want some kind of an iterated next function or macro/inline-function where your `p=p->next` is encapsulated.

```
struct list { struct list *next; };
struct list *iterated_next(struct list *p, int x){ 
   for(int i=0; i<x;i++) p=p->next; return p; 
}
```

I don't the point in avoiding `p=p->next`. It's just notation.
If it's encapsulated, it doesn't have any effect observable from outside.

With the above, notice that if you then do:

```
struct list *iterated_next3(struct list *p){
    return iterated_next(p,3);
}
```

on either gcc and clang with optimizations on (the small iteration count will
make optimizing compilers want to inline the function and unroll the loop), you will get (x86_64):

```
iterated_next3:
        movq    (%rdi), %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        ret
```

which is absolutely the same thing as what you'd get from (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zM684oxex):

```
struct list *iterated_next3_(struct list *p){
    return p->next->next->next;
}
```

, reinforcing the point that insisting on no `p=p->next` is not a very reasonable requirement.

Of course, you can achieve the same effects with a recursion-based iterated_next and without a spelled-out `p=p->next` (see [0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/0)'s answer), but that's tail recursion, which will want to get optimized into an effective while loop anyway, so I'd stick to a `p=p->next` loop as I find that more descriptive of the algorithm.